# Rails 4.0 and Dynamic Fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm re-writing/upgrading a 3.0 Application that uses dynamic fields based on this pro Railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/403-dynamic-forms.

The way that it loads the dynamic fields is through the following code:

```
  <%= f.hidden_field :tour_type_id %>

  <%= f.fields_for :options, OpenStruct.new(@trip.options) do |builder| %>
     <% @trip.tour_type.type_fields.where(:variable => false).each do |field| %>
           <%= render "type_fields", field: field, f: builder %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

This is rendering the html correctly.

When I execute a create through the console the hash i'm passing in for :options is saving correctly. However, when I submit the values through  the form it saves the value of the hash as nil.

I'm thinking it's possibly because of the strong params I have in the controller.

```
  def trip_params
     params.require(:trip).permit(:options => {:id => :value})
  end
```

I also tried

```
  def trip_params
     params.require(:trip).permit(:options => {})
  end
```

The params look okay in the rails server log, but somehow before the update occurs the value for the options is being set to nil

```
  Processing by TripsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "trip"=>{"options"=>{"1"=>"400"}}, "commit"=>"Update Trip", "id"=>"1"}

 SQL (1.0ms)  UPDATE "trips" SET "updated_at" = $1, "options" = $2 WHERE "trips"."id" = 1  [["updated_at", Mon, 26 Aug 2013 05:13:35 UTC +00:00], ["options", "--- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters\n'1': \n"]]
```

I also added the serialize action to the model

```
 class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
   serialize :options, Hash
 end
```

I don't really know why this code isn't working in Rails v 4, Ruby V 1.9.3.

This code is modeled off of the dynamic forms RailsCast.

EDIT:

I tried the solution in outlined here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#outside-the-scope-of-strong-parameters

```
def trip_params
  params.require(:trip).permit(
    :admin_name, 
    :brochure_title, 
    :description, 
    :organized_by, 
    :start_date, 
    :end_date, 
    :tour_type_id, 
    :pay_by, 
    :extension
  ).tap do |whitelisted|
    whitelisted[:options] = params[:trip][:options]
  end
end
```

and i'm now getting a found unpermitted parameters :options error.

Comment: `params.require(:trip).permit!(:options)` can you please try this

Comment: @RajarshiDas `permit!` doesn't take argument http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit-21

Comment: ooh sorry it should not be exclamatory over there `params.require(:trip).permit(:options)` thanks @j03w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `strong_parameters` does not support permitting hash with arbitrary keys, and I think it's for a good reason…

There is a solution suggested on rails github repo: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9454#issuecomment-14167664 and on *RailsGuides* http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#outside-the-scope-of-strong-parameters

For your case it would be something like this

```
params.require(:trip).permit(:foo, :bar, :baz).tap do |whitelisted|
  whitelisted[:options] = params[:trip][:options]
end
```

If `options` is your only attribute for `Trip` then that is as good as

```
params.require(:trip).permit!
```

Comment: options is not the only attribute. So in the example above :foo, :bar, :baz are the other field names, and then the block whitelists the hash with arbitrary keys?

Comment: @Hillary yes, exactly

Comment: @Hillary hmm odd… what's the exact error? Mind updating to your original question?

Comment: try `whitelisted[:options] = params.require(:trip).slice(:options).permit!` This is untested though

Comment: Still get the unpermitted params error for options. could the issue be because of the html of the dynamic field.

Comment: finally getting back to the upgrade, and the first answer worked for upgrading the code.